# While Copying a csv file to Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Im creating this table

```
CREATE TABLE StateProvince( StateProvinceID SERIAL, StateProvinceCode char(3) NOT NULL, CountryRegionCode varchar(3) NOT NULL,
```

when i import the data from a csv file

```
SELECT 'Copying data into Person.StateProvince'; copy Person.StateProvince FROM 'C:\Users\Ernesto Cabrera\Desktop\Prueba\StateProvidence.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

these appears

> ERROR: invalid input syntax for type integer: "0" CONTEXT: COPY
> stateprovince, line 1, column stateprovinceid: "0" SQL state: 22P02

Comment: You try to copy the character '0' as an integer in postgres. Do you have a header in your csv file ?

Comment: Is the 0 in double quotes in the file?

Comment: Hi, the file doesnt have headers and in the file the 0 doesnt have double quotes

Comment: Inspect the file with some kind of tool for inspecting binary files, like `od`.  There may be unprintable characters near the zero digit.

Comment: What is the client you are doing this in? What is the database encoding, in `psql` do `show lc_ctype` and for the client encoding do `show client_encoding ;`. Add as update to your question.

Comment: show lc_ctype is "English_United States.1252"
show  show client_encoding ; is UNICODE